Confidence intervals for the ratio of marginal effects? (GAM Regression)
I have a question on how to adapt confidence intervals for marginal effects.
I have some data in R (response is between 0 and 1, t is a time variable, predictors are continuous and greater than 0):
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(marginaleffects)

set.seed(123)

n <- 500
t <- seq(0, 365, length.out = n) 
x1 <- rnorm(n, mean = 100, sd = 10)  
x2 <- rpois(n, lambda = 2)  

true_mean <- function(t, x1, x2) {
    base <- 0.4  
    x1_effect <- 0.003 * x1 * exp(-t/200) 
    x2_effect <- 0.05 * x2 * (1 - exp(-t/200))  
    time_effect <- 0.1 * sin(2 * pi * t/365) 
    return(base + x1_effect + x2_effect + time_effect)
}

y_mean <- true_mean(t, x1, x2)
y <- plogis(qlogis(y_mean) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.3)) 

sim_data <- data.frame(
    y = y,
    t = t,
    x1 = x1,
    x2 = x2
)

I fit a GAM regression to this:
$$ g(\mathbb{E}[Y_i]) = \beta_0 + f_1(t_i, x1_i) + f_2(t_i, x2_i) $$

$g(\cdot)$ is the logit link function $g(p) = \log(\frac{p}{1-p})$
$Y_i$ is a Beta distribution :  $Y_i \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta) $
$\beta_0$ is the intercept
$f_1$ and $f_2$ are smooth functions for the interaction effects between:($t$ and $x_1$)
and ($t$ and $x_2$)

Here is the R code:
  gam_model <- gam(
        y ~ te(t, x1) + te(t, x2),
        data = sim_data,
        family = betar(link = "logit"),
        method = "REML"
    )

Using this link (https://marginaleffects.com/bonus/gam.html), I wrote R code to find the marginal effects of each predictor on the response (over time) -  this involved creating a grid of points and calculating the marginal effects over the grid:
get_marginal_effects <- function(model, variable, data, time_points) {
    effects_list <- list()
    
    for(curr_time in time_points) {
        newdata <- data.frame(
            t = curr_time,
            x1 = mean(data$x1),
            x2 = mean(data$x2)
        )
        
        mfx <- slopes(model, 
                     variables = variable,
                     newdata = newdata)
        
       
        effects_list[[as.character(curr_time)]] <- data.frame(
            time = curr_time,
            effect = mfx$estimate * 100,  
            conf_low = mfx$conf.low * 100,
            conf_high = mfx$conf.high * 100
        )
    }
    
    return(do.call(rbind, effects_list))
}

time_points <- seq(0, 365, length.out = 50)
x1_effects <- get_marginal_effects(gam_model, "x1", sim_data, time_points)
x2_effects <- get_marginal_effects(gam_model, "x2", sim_data, time_points)

plot_effects <- function(effects_data, title, color) {
    ggplot(effects_data, aes(x = time)) +
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf_low, ymax = conf_high),
                   fill = color, alpha = 0.2) +
        geom_line(aes(y = effect), 
                 color = color, size = 1) +
        geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed",
                  color = "gray50") +
        theme_minimal() +
        labs(
            title = title,
            x = "Days",
            y = "Change in Response (%)"
        ) +
        theme(
            plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
        )
}

p1 <- plot_effects(x1_effects, "Marginal Effect of X1 Over Time", "#4E79A7")
p2 <- plot_effects(x2_effects, "Marginal Effect of X2 Over Time", "#E15759")


Now, I was curious in combining these plots into single plots. For example, the ratio of the two marginal effects over time, or the difference of these marginal effects over time.
Naively, I thought I could just do this as follows:
effects_comparison <- data.frame(
    time = x1_effects$time,
    ratio = x1_effects$effect / x2_effects$effect,
    ratio_se = abs(x1_effects$effect / x2_effects$effect) * 
        sqrt((x1_effects$conf_high - x1_effects$conf_low)^2/(4*x1_effects$effect^2) +
                 (x2_effects$conf_high - x2_effects$conf_low)^2/(4*x2_effects$effect^2)),
    difference = x1_effects$effect - x2_effects$effect,
    diff_se = sqrt((x1_effects$conf_high - x1_effects$conf_low)^2/4 +
                       (x2_effects$conf_high - x2_effects$conf_low)^2/4)
)

effects_comparison$ratio_conf_low <- effects_comparison$ratio - 1.96 * effects_comparison$ratio_se
effects_comparison$ratio_conf_high <- effects_comparison$ratio + 1.96 * effects_comparison$ratio_se
effects_comparison$diff_conf_low <- effects_comparison$difference - 1.96 * effects_comparison$diff_se
effects_comparison$diff_conf_high <- effects_comparison$difference + 1.96 * effects_comparison$diff_se

ratio_plot <- ggplot(effects_comparison, aes(x = time)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ratio_conf_low, ymax = ratio_conf_high),
                fill = "purple", alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line(aes(y = ratio), 
              color = "purple", size = 1) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed",
               color = "gray50") +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(
        title = "Ratio of Marginal Effects (X1/X2) Over Time",
        x = "Days",
        y = "Ratio of Effects"
    ) +
    theme(
        plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
    )

difference_plot <- ggplot(effects_comparison, aes(x = time)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = diff_conf_low, ymax = diff_conf_high),
                fill = "darkgreen", alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line(aes(y = difference), 
              color = "darkgreen", size = 1) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed",
               color = "gray50") +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(
        title = "Difference in Marginal Effects (X1-X2) Over Time",
        x = "Days",
        y = "Difference in Effects (%)"
    ) +
    theme(
        plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
    )

print(ratio_plot)
print(difference_plot)


But I am not sure if this correct? Is it possible to simply perform arithmetic operations (e.g. differences, ratios) on marginal effects produced from regression models, and naively adjust their confidence intervals? Or is there a far more statistically sound procedure for this which I have oversimplified?

Footnotes:

For the sum of two random variables Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2 Cov(X,Y) ... but for the ratio of two random variables, e.g. Var(X/Y), this is far more complicated and probably involves convolutions ....my confidence interval approach is simpler ... however, it is possible that my approach might approximate the true variance well enough, however I am uncertain)

If there was no time term, I could have used the bootstrap to calculate ratios of marginal effects produced from GAMs on different bootstrap samples. However, the time term makes the bootstrap process complicated as random samples will destroy the time sequence.



First, a more code-efficient way to compute the two sets of slopes and plot them. Note that datagrid() holds unspecified variables at their means (or modes) automatically. Note that variables allows you to compute slopes with respect to multiple variables at once.
slo <- slopes(
  gam_model,
  variables = c("x1", "x2"),
  newdata = datagrid(t = seq(0, 365, length.out = 50))
)

ggplot(slo, aes(t, estimate, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, fill = term)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(alpha = .3) +
  labs(y = "Slope", x = "t") +
  theme_minimal()


Now, the ratio you are asking for is an "exotic" quantity, not built in in the marginaleffects package by default. However, it is very easy to compute by building a custom aggregation/differencing function for the hypothesis argument. See this section for details and other examples: https://marginaleffects.com/bonus/hypothesis.html#functions

hyp = function(x) {
  out = aggregate(estimate ~ t, FUN = \(x) x[1] / x[2], data = x)
  colnames(out)[1] = "term"
  return(out)
}
slo <- slopes(
  gam_model,
  hypothesis = hyp,
  variables = c("x1", "x2"),
  newdata = datagrid(t = seq(0, 365, length.out = 50))
)
slo
#> 
#>    Term Estimate Std. Error     z Pr(>|z|)   S   2.5 % 97.5 %
#>    0.00   0.9728     2.6711 0.364    0.716 0.5 -4.2625 6.2081
#>    7.45   0.7273     1.4111 0.515    0.606 0.7 -2.0384 3.4930
#>   14.90   0.5687     0.8185 0.695    0.487 1.0 -1.0354 2.1729
#>   22.35   0.4582     0.5060 0.906    0.365 1.5 -0.5335 1.4499
#>   29.80   0.3769     0.3307 1.140    0.254 2.0 -0.2711 1.0250
#> --- 40 rows omitted. See ?avg_slopes and ?print.marginaleffects --- 
#>  335.20   0.0146     0.0234 0.624    0.532 0.9 -0.0313 0.0605
#>  342.65   0.0137     0.0255 0.538    0.591 0.8 -0.0363 0.0637
#>  350.10   0.0129     0.0283 0.454    0.650 0.6 -0.0427 0.0684
#>  357.55   0.0121     0.0317 0.381    0.703 0.5 -0.0500 0.0742
#>  365.00   0.0113     0.0353 0.320    0.749 0.4 -0.0579 0.0805
#> Type:  response 
#> Columns: term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high

ggplot(slo, aes(term, estimate, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(alpha = .3) +
  labs(y = "Ratio", x = "t") +
  theme_minimal()



thanks Vincent for this answer!

a question: how do I know that the confidence interval corresponding to the ratio is statistically correct? are you using some resampling for this?

I had an idea on a theoretical approach that might be applicable for this problem? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/657271/can-we-bootstrap-regression-coefficients-instead-of-data

The confidence intervals are computed via the delta method, with the usual caveats.

Vincent: Wow, this is so elegant!  R is able to implement the delta method by itself on some user defined parameter? In which part of the R code did you specify this (i.e. the delta method)?

marginaleffects uses the delta method by default. It can also bootstrap or do simulation-based inference. This is all documented exhaustively on marginaleffects.com and in the package documentation.

Thank you for everything Vincent .... I posted a question on how to use the parametric bootstrap for this same problem (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/657477/learning-to-do-the-parametric-bootstrap) ... I wonder if we will get similar results...

question: I thought that the delta method produces a single variance estimate - how were you able to get changing variance estimates across? I think you evaluated the delta method over a range of points?
