Can we bootstrap regression coefficients instead of data?
I have a question about using the bootstrap in situations (e.g. Confidence intervals for the ratio of marginal effects? (GAM Regression)) where the traditional bootstrap method might be complicated (e.g. longitudinal/clustered data, irregular parameter e.g. ratio of two marginal effect estimates, etc).
Here is my interpretation of the traditional bootstrap:

Original model: $y_i = X_i\beta + \epsilon_i$
Original estimates: $\hat{\beta}$ from fitting model to $(y_i, X_i)$ for $i=1,...,n$
For bootstrap iteration $b = 1,...,B$:

Resample with replacement from $(y_i, X_i)$ to get $(y_i^{(b)}, X_i^{(b)})$
Get $\hat{\beta}^{(b)}$ by fitting model to each bootstrap sample


Bootstrap distribution comes from $\{\hat{\beta}^{(1)},...,\hat{\beta}^{(B)}\}$

I was thinking that when this traditional bootstrap method might not be possible to implement, perhaps we could use the asymptotic variance properties of the parameter estimates to derive bootstrap estimates?

For example, suppose I fit a regression model to some data. Using asymptotic variance properties, I know that (for the specific type of model):
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix} \hat{\beta}_1 \\ \hat{\beta}_2 \end{pmatrix} \sim N\left(\begin{pmatrix} \beta_1 \\ \beta_2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_{11} & \sigma_{12} \\ \sigma_{12} & \sigma_{22} \end{pmatrix}\right)
$$

Now, for $s = 1,...,S$, I draw samples from a Multivariate Normal Distribution:

Generate:
$$\begin{pmatrix} \beta_1^{(s)} \\ \beta_2^{(s)} \end{pmatrix} \sim N\left(\begin{pmatrix} \hat{\beta}_1 \\ \hat{\beta}_2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \hat{\sigma}_{11} & \hat{\sigma}_{12} \\ \hat{\sigma}_{12} & \hat{\sigma}_{22} \end{pmatrix}\right)$$




Suppose I am interested in some quantity $\hat{\theta}$ that depends on $\hat{\beta_1}$ and $\hat{\beta_2}$, e.g. $\hat{\theta} = \hat{\beta_1} / \hat{\beta_2}$. This is an irregular parameter where deriving analytical formulas for the variance could be quite complicated depending on the model.


I now calculate ratio $\theta^{(s)} = \beta_1^{(s)}/\beta_2^{(s)}$

And the distribution of $\theta$ comes from $\{\theta^{(1)},...,\theta^{(S)}\}$


Is this a statistically valid approach for obtaining confidence intervals when the bootstrap method is not possible? That is, is it possible to bootstrap regression coefficients (by simulating from their joint distribution) instead of bootstrapping the data?


Note: Special attention would need to be provided to determine the correct joint probability distribution of the regression coefficients.



My interpretation of the bootstrap method suggested by ChrisL:


For outer loop $b = 1,...,B$:

Sample new covariance matrix (e.g., using Wishart distribution):
$$ \hat{\Sigma}^{(b)} \sim W^{-1}(\hat{\Sigma}, \nu) $$


For inner loop $s = 1,...,S$:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \beta_1^{(b,s)} \\ \beta_2^{(b,s)} \end{pmatrix} \sim N\left(\hat{\beta}, \hat{\Sigma}^{(b)}\right) $$

Calculate ratio for each combination:
$$ \theta^{(b,s)} = \beta_1^{(b,s)}/\beta_2^{(b,s)} $$

The distribution of $\theta$ comes from:
$$ \{\theta^{(b,s)}: b = 1,...,B; s = 1,...,S\} $$


I thought the Wishart distribution would be a good choice since the sampling distribution in the univariate case is generally Chi Square Distribution (and the Wishart is closely related to the Chi Square Distribution). I think this new approach might allow for better uncertainty estimates?

I guess that when you bootstrap the confidence interval of ratio of the coefficients with the usual approach, the estimate of the confidence intervals accounts for the uncertainty in estimates of $\sigma_{ij}$ while the approach you suggest does not. You would need something like a nested approach where you first sample the sigmas and then the betas.

It sounds like you are describing a parametric bootstrap.

thank you everyone! Can you please tell me how I would  account for $\sigma_ij$ in the second approach used in my question?

ChrisL: Please see the updates

@user_436830 your outline of the nested bootstrap approach seems reasonable. However, as Noah answered, if the $\hat{\sigma_{ij}}$ already quantify the uncertainty of the estimates $\hat{\beta}$ then the outer loop should be not necessary.

Yes, this is not a bootstrap (even a parametric bootstrap), but is known as "simulation-based inference". It is implemented in the clarify package for R (of which I am the author) and described in a few papers, including Herron (1999), King et al. (2000), and Rainey (2023) (note, this paper has a correction). It is an alternative to the delta method for computing "derived quantities", i.e., quantities derived from regression coefficients, like your $\theta$. Inference can be performed either by using the variance of the simulated distribution of the derived quantity in a Wald formula or by using the quantiles of the distribution as confidence interval bounds.
There are some special cases where it has been compared to the delta method, but overall its performance is not well studied. It often yields similar results to the delta method, but quantile-based inference doesn't require that the quantity is normally distributed (only that some possibly unknown transformation of it is). Unlike the delta method, it is subject to Monte Carlo error (i.e., variation across different analyses when using the same dataset based on the seed), but this can be reduced by increasing the number of simulation iterations. It tends to be much faster than the bootstrap because the model doesn't need to be refit in each simulation, but it relies on the assumption that the model parameters are normally distributed.
See this answer and the clarify website for examples.

References
Herron, M. C. (1999). Postestimation Uncertainty in Limited Dependent Variable Models. Political Analysis, 8(1), 83–98. https://doi.org/10.1093/oxfordjournals.pan.a029806
King, G., Tomz, M., & Wittenberg, J. (2000). Making the Most of Statistical Analyses: Improving Interpretation and Presentation. American Journal of Political Science, 44(2), 347–361. https://doi.org/10.2307/2669316
Rainey, C. (2023). A careful consideration of CLARIFY: Simulation-induced bias in point estimates of quantities of interest. Political Science Research and Methods, 1–10. https://doi.org/10.1017/psrm.2023.8

thanks Noah! Someone else wrote that the formula in my question does not account for the uncertainty contained in $\sigma_ij$ . Is that correct? would I include it?

$\sigma_{ij}$ is not a model parameter; it itself is a quantification of the uncertainty of the model parameter. Using $\hat{\sigma}_{ij}$ already yields valid inference for $\hat\theta$; you don't need to further account for uncertainty.

Noah: I have updated my question to include my interpretation of the modified approach

@user_436830 I think that is unnecessary and overcomplicated this. ChrisL misinterpreted your original approach and didn't see that this is a well-established method as I described. ChrisL might have thought the $\sigma_{ij}$ were model parameters, but they are not. If they were, you would have to sample them.

thank you - I accepted your answer. I thought that $\sigma_{ij}$ are model parameters?

$\sigma_{ij}$ is the variance of the sampling distribution of $\hat\beta$. As you said, this comes from the asymptotic properties of the model and method of estimation. It is not a part of the model. Nowhere in the model do you specify the distribution of $\hat\beta$. There are many ways to compute $\sigma_{ij}$, like using the usual maximum likelihood estimator, or bootstrapping, or robust variance, etc. You still have to get that step right in order for your inference on $\hat\theta$ to be valid. Traditional bootstrapping allows you not to have to get that right.

@Noah I did not know that this is a well established approach. +1  Thank you for the clarification and the references in your answer. I am happy to learn about this method.
