Learning to do the parametric bootstrap
I learned about the parametric bootstrap (Can we bootstrap regression coefficients instead of data?) and I am interested in applying this method to determine the confidence interval on the ratio of two marginal effects of a GAM regression model (Confidence intervals for the ratio of marginal effects? (GAM Regression)). I would like to learn how to implement the parametric bootstrap myself on a real problem.
Here is the R code for the data I am using (response is between 0 and 1, t is a time variable, predictors are continuous and greater than 0):
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(marginaleffects)

set.seed(123)

n <- 500
t <- seq(0, 365, length.out = n) 
x1 <- rnorm(n, mean = 100, sd = 10)  
x2 <- rpois(n, lambda = 2)  

true_mean <- function(t, x1, x2) {
    base <- 0.4  
    x1_effect <- 0.003 * x1 * exp(-t/200) 
    x2_effect <- 0.05 * x2 * (1 - exp(-t/200))  
    time_effect <- 0.1 * sin(2 * pi * t/365) 
    return(base + x1_effect + x2_effect + time_effect)
}

y_mean <- true_mean(t, x1, x2)
y <- plogis(qlogis(y_mean) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.3)) 

sim_data <- data.frame(
    y = y,
    t = t,
    x1 = x1,
    x2 = x2
)

Here is the regression model:
$$ g(\mathbb{E}[Y_i]) = \beta_0 + f_1(t_i, x1_i) + f_2(t_i, x2_i) $$

$g(\cdot)$ is the logit link function $g(p) = \log(\frac{p}{1-p})$
$Y_i$ is a Beta distribution :  $Y_i \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta) $
$\beta_0$ is the intercept
$f_1$ and $f_2$ are smooth functions for the interaction effects between:($t$ and $x_1$)
and ($t$ and $x_2$)

The parametric bootstrap seems to rely on the fact that the joint distribution of parameter estimates is asymptotically multivariate normal:
$$\hat{\beta} \sim \mathcal{N}(\beta, \Sigma)$$
$$\beta^{(s)} \sim \mathcal{N}(\hat{\beta}, \hat{\Sigma})$$
I researched how to get the mean vector and variance-covariance matrix from a fitted GAM regression:
gam_model <- gam(
    y ~ te(t, x1) + te(t, x2),
    data = sim_data,
    family = betar(link = "logit"),
    method = "REML"
)

beta_hat <- coef(gam_model)
vcov_matrix <- vcov(gam_model)

Finally, this is where the parametric bootstrap method is setup. I sample from this multivariate normal, and calculate the marginal effect ratio again and again. For two variables $x_1$ and $x_2$, let's say their marginal effects are $m_1(\beta)$ and $m_2(\beta)$. The ratio of interest is:
$$r(\beta) = \frac{m_1(\beta)}{m_2(\beta)}$$
To estimate via parametric bootstrap:

Draw $S$ samples: $\beta^{(1)}, \beta^{(2)}, ..., \beta^{(S)}$
Calculate ratio for each: $r^{(s)} = r(\beta^{(s)})$
Calculate sample variance (where $\bar{r} = \frac{1}{S}\sum_{s=1}^S r^{(s)}$):

$$\widehat{\text{Var}}(r) = \frac{1}{S-1}\sum_{s=1}^S (r^{(s)} - \bar{r})^2$$
This is the R code for the parametric bootstrap (I only did 10 simulations for brevity, I would ideally I try to do far more):
time_points <- seq(0, 365, length.out = 50)

n_sims <- 10
results <- list()

for(s in 1:n_sims) {
       
    sim_coefs <- mvrnorm(n = 1, mu = beta_hat, Sigma = vcov_matrix)
    
    sim_model <- gam_model
    sim_model$coefficients <- sim_coefs
    
    effects <- sapply(time_points, function(curr_time) {
        newdata <- data.frame(
            t = curr_time,
            x1 = mean(sim_data$x1),
            x2 = mean(sim_data$x2)
        )
        
        x1_mfx <- slopes(sim_model, variables = "x1", newdata = newdata)
        x2_mfx <- slopes(sim_model, variables = "x2", newdata = newdata)
        
        c(x1_effect = x1_mfx$estimate * 100,
          x2_effect = x2_mfx$estimate * 100)
    })
    
    results[[s]] <- data.frame(
        time = time_points,
        x1_effect = effects["x1_effect",],
        x2_effect = effects["x2_effect",],
        ratio = effects["x1_effect",] / effects["x2_effect",]
    )
}

all_results <- bind_rows(results, .id = "sim")

Plotting the results of the Parametric Bootstrap looks like this:
summary_stats <- all_results %>%
    group_by(time) %>%
    summarize(
        ratio_mean = mean(ratio),
        ratio_sd = sd(ratio),
        ratio_lower = quantile(ratio, 0.025),
        ratio_upper = quantile(ratio, 0.975)
    )

 ggplot(summary_stats, aes(x = time)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ratio_lower, ymax = ratio_upper),
                fill = "purple", alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line(aes(y = ratio_mean),
              color = "purple", size = 1) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed",
               color = "gray50") +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(
        title = "Ratio of Marginal Effects (X1/X2) Over Time",
        subtitle = paste("Based on", n_sims, "bootstrap iterations"),
        x = "Days",
        y = "Ratio of Effects"
    )


Did I do this correctly? (I wonder if there are any faster ways to do this, e.g. parallelize, pre-built R packages for parametric bootstrap)

UPDATE: Parallel function:
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

set.seed(123)
n <- 500
t <- seq(0, 365, length.out = n) 
x1 <- rnorm(n, mean = 100, sd = 10)  
x2 <- rpois(n, lambda = 2)  

true_mean <- function(t, x1, x2) {
    base <- 0.4  
    x1_effect <- 0.003 * x1 * exp(-t/200) 
    x2_effect <- 0.05 * x2 * (1 - exp(-t/200))  
    time_effect <- 0.1 * sin(2 * pi * t/365) 
    return(base + x1_effect + x2_effect + time_effect)
}

y_mean <- true_mean(t, x1, x2)
y <- plogis(qlogis(y_mean) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.3)) 

sim_data <- data.frame(
    y = y,
    t = t,
    x1 = x1,
    x2 = x2
)

# Fit GAM model
gam_model <- gam(
    y ~ te(t, x1) + te(t, x2),
    data = sim_data,
    family = betar(link = "logit"),
    method = "REML"
)

# Function for parallel bootstrap
get_bootstrap_effects <- function(model, sim_data, n_sims = 100, n_cores = parallel::detectCores() - 1) {
    cl <- makeCluster(n_cores)
    registerDoParallel(cl)
    
    beta_hat <- coef(model)
    vcov_matrix <- vcov(model)
    
    t_seq <- seq(min(sim_data$t), max(sim_data$t), length.out = 50)
    x1_mean <- mean(sim_data$x1)
    x2_mean <- mean(sim_data$x2)
    
    pkg_env <- new.env()
    pkg_env$model <- model
    pkg_env$t_seq <- t_seq
    pkg_env$beta_hat <- beta_hat
    pkg_env$vcov_matrix <- vcov_matrix
    pkg_env$x1_mean <- x1_mean
    pkg_env$x2_mean <- x2_mean
    
    clusterExport(cl, ls(pkg_env), envir = pkg_env)
    
    clusterEvalQ(cl, {
        library(MASS)
        library(mgcv)
    })
    
    results_list <- foreach(s = 1:n_sims, 
                            .packages = c("dplyr"),
                            .errorhandling = "pass") %dopar% {
                                tryCatch({
                                    sim_coefs <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = 1, mu = beta_hat, Sigma = vcov_matrix)
                                    
                                    sim_model <- model
                                    sim_model$coefficients <- sim_coefs
                                    
                                    effects <- matrix(NA, nrow = 2, ncol = length(t_seq))
                                    rownames(effects) <- c("x1_effect", "x2_effect")
                                    
                                    for(i in seq_along(t_seq)) {
                                        newdata_x1 <- data.frame(
                                            t = t_seq[i],
                                            x1 = x1_mean + 0.1,
                                            x2 = x2_mean
                                        )
                                        newdata_base <- data.frame(
                                            t = t_seq[i],
                                            x1 = x1_mean,
                                            x2 = x2_mean
                                        )
                                        
                                        x1_effect <- (predict(sim_model, newdata_x1) - 
                                                          predict(sim_model, newdata_base)) / 0.1
                                        
                                        newdata_x2 <- data.frame(
                                            t = t_seq[i],
                                            x1 = x1_mean,
                                            x2 = x2_mean + 0.1
                                        )
                                        
                                        x2_effect <- (predict(sim_model, newdata_x2) - 
                                                          predict(sim_model, newdata_base)) / 0.1
                                        
                                        effects[,i] <- c(x1_effect, x2_effect)
                                    }
                                    
                                    data.frame(
                                        sim = s,
                                        t = t_seq,
                                        x1_effect = effects["x1_effect",],
                                        x2_effect = effects["x2_effect",],
                                        ratio = effects["x1_effect",] / effects["x2_effect",]
                                    )
                                }, error = function(e) NULL)
                            }
    
    stopCluster(cl)
    
    valid_results <- results_list[!sapply(results_list, is.null)]
    all_results <- do.call(rbind, valid_results)
    
    results_summary <- all_results %>%
        group_by(t) %>%
        summarize(
            ratio_mean = mean(ratio, na.rm = TRUE),
            ratio_sd = sd(ratio, na.rm = TRUE),
            ratio_lower = quantile(ratio, 0.025, na.rm = TRUE),
            ratio_upper = quantile(ratio, 0.975, na.rm = TRUE),
            x1_mean = mean(x1_effect, na.rm = TRUE),
            x2_mean = mean(x2_effect, na.rm = TRUE)
        )
    
    ratio_plot <- ggplot(results_summary, aes(x = t)) +
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ratio_lower, ymax = ratio_upper),
                    fill = "purple", alpha = 0.2) +
        geom_line(aes(y = ratio_mean),
                  color = "purple", size = 1) +
        geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed",
                   color = "gray50") +
        theme_minimal() +
        labs(
            title = "Ratio of X1 to X2 Effects Over Time",
            subtitle = paste("Based on", length(valid_results), "bootstrap iterations"),
            x = "Time",
            y = "Effect Ratio (X1/X2)"
        )
    
    return(list(
        plot = ratio_plot,
        all_results = all_results,
        summary = results_summary
    ))
}

bootstrap_results <- get_bootstrap_effects(gam_model, sim_data, n_sims = 100)
print(bootstrap_results$plot)


